# how to get all the hash tables from second file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a script that opens a *.pl file, and want it to print all the hash tables in this file. Is there any way to do this without knowing the hash tables names ?

```
use Switch;
LOG("in a.pl");
# ----------------------------------------------------


%hash1 = (
        abc_abc_123 => "xx",
        abc_efg_321 => "zz",
 );

%hash2 = (
        abc_abc_456 => "uu",
        abc_efg_654 => "ii",
 );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give an example of the opened .pl file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid file that will load (unlike your example) with hashes in this works.  It looks for things that match alphanumeric in the main:: package and that have changed during the import of stuff from the require

```
use Data::Dumper;


sub show_hashes_from_file {
    my $filename=shift;
    my %snap=%main::;
    require $filename;
    my @hnames=grep(not(exists($snap{$_})) && /^[\w\d]+$/ && $_ ne $filename, keys %main::);
    for my $name (@hnames) {
    $stuff=\%{$main::{$name}};
    print "$name ",Dumper($stuff) if (scalar keys(%$stuff) > 0);
    }
}

show_hashes_from_file("hashes.pl");
```

You might like to look at the "package" keyword, save having all these hashes in the main namespace